# Find maximum signed short integer in python

Tags: python, struct

**How do I get the maximum signed short integer in Python** (i.e. SHRT_MAX in C's limits.h)**?**

I want to normalize samples from a single channel of a `*.wav` file, so instead of a bunch of 16-bit signed integers, I want a bunch of floats between 1 and -1.  Here's what I've got (the pertinent code is in the `normalized_samples()` function):

```
def samples(clip, chan_no = 0):
    # *.wav files generally come in 8-bit unsigned ints or 16-bit signed ints
    # python's wave module gives sample width in bytes, so STRUCT_FMT
    # basically converts the wave.samplewidth into a struct fmt string
    STRUCT_FMT = {  1 : 'B',
                    2 : 'h' }

    for i in range(clip.getnframes()):
        yield struct.unpack(STRUCT_FMT[clip.getsampwidth()] * clip.getnchannels(), 
                clip.readframes(1))[chan_no]

def normalized_samples(clip, chan_no = 0):
    for sample in samples(clip, chan_no):
        yield float(sample) / float(32767) ### THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
```

Comment: If they are 16 bit samples then you divide them by 32768, no matter what the size of the largest regular integer is. python has only two kinds of integers until version 3, a "regular" limited size int and an unlimited binint. There is no short int type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in module sys, sys.maxint. Though I'm not sure that is the correct way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

GregS is right, this is not the right way to solve the problem.  If your samples are known 8 or 16 bit, you don't want to be dividing them by a number that varies by platform.

You may be running into trouble because a signed 16-bit int actually ranges from -32768 to 32767.  Dividing by 32767 is going to give you < -1 in the extreme negative case.

Try this:

yield float(sample + 2**15) / 2**15 - 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using **cython**

**getlimit.py**

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import limits

print limits.shrt_max
```

**limits.pyx**

```
import cython
cdef extern from "limits.h":
    cdef int SHRT_MAX

shrt_max = SHRT_MAX
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine circumstances on a modern computer (i.e. one that uses 2's complement integers) where this would fail:

```
assert -32768 <= signed_16_bit_integer <= 32767
```

To do exactly what you asked for:

```
if signed_16_bit_integer >= 0:
    afloat = signed_16_bit_integer / 32767.0
else:
    afloat = signed_16_bit_integer / -32768.0
```

Having read your code a bit more closely: you have sample_width_in_bytes so just divide by 255 or 256 if it's `B` and by 32768 if it's `h`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

# maximums.py

####################################333#########################

B16_MAX = (1 << 16) - 1
B15_MAX = (1 << 15) - 1
B08_MAX = (1 <<  8) - 1
B07_MAX = (1 <<  7) - 1

print
print "hex(B16_MAX) =",hex(B16_MAX) # 0xffff
print "hex(B15_MAX) =",hex(B15_MAX) # 0x7fff
print "hex(B08_MAX) =",hex(B08_MAX) #   0xff
print "hex(B07_MAX) =",hex(B07_MAX) #   0x7f
print

####################################333#########################

UBYTE2_MAX = B16_MAX
SBYTE2_MAX = B15_MAX
UBYTE1_MAX = B08_MAX
SBYTE1_MAX = B07_MAX

print
print "UBYTE2_MAX =",UBYTE2_MAX # 65535
print "SBYTE2_MAX =",SBYTE2_MAX # 32767
print "UBYTE1_MAX =",UBYTE1_MAX #   255
print "SBYTE1_MAX =",SBYTE1_MAX #   127
print

####################################333#########################

USHRT_MAX = UBYTE2_MAX
SHRT_MAX  = SBYTE2_MAX
CHAR_MAX  = UBYTE1_MAX
BYTE_MAX  = SBYTE1_MAX

print
print "USHRT_MAX =",USHRT_MAX # 65535
print " SHRT_MAX =", SHRT_MAX # 32767
print " CHAR_MAX =", CHAR_MAX #   255
print " BYTE_MAX =", BYTE_MAX #   127
print

####################################333#########################
```